# Date query ran in PL/SQL Developer shows time, but does not show in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

The same query ran in PL/SQL Developer shows time, however it does not show in Oracle SQL Developer. Is there a way to get the time in SQL Developer?

In SQL Developer: 
[image]

In PL/SQL:

[image]

This is the details of the date field:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change this in the *Tools / Preferences* dialog of SQL developer:

1. Select *Database* / *NLS Parameters* in the tree view on the left.
2. Then put `dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss` into the *Date Format* field.
3. Press *OK* to close the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

To make it simple:
use to_char() function, it will work with SQL developer as well as Pl/sql.

select to_char(sysdate,'MM-DD-YYYY HH:Mi:SS') from table_name;

Answer (score 0):

Can't see your query, but in oracle, it would look like this:

```
 select sysdate from dual
```