# count the last login for each user per day

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to count last login for each user per day.?

Table looks similar to this

```
id  name   Date 
-----------------
1    a    01-Feb-2017
2    a    01-Feb-2017
3    a    01-Feb-2017
4    b    02-Feb-2017
5    b    02-Feb-2017
6    c    04-Feb-2017
7    c    04-Feb-2017
```

1. All i want to do is put to_char(date,'dd-mm-yy-hh-mm-ss) to the date as my date do not have times in it.
2. Fetch the latest login for user a on 1-feb-2017 , user b on 2-feb-2017 and user c on 4-feb-2017
3. One user can login multiple times, so the dates are printed many times, but i want to show only last login date.

Kindly let me know please.....looks simple but i'm stuck

Comment: In some (most) case, this could be done with `GROUP BY` and using `MAX(date)` (depends on the DBMS)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Comment: Column data types?

Comment: ID = number , name = varchar , Date

Comment: Sql Developer- Database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to count last login for each user per day.?

Group the results by user (i.e. `name`) and each day (i.e. `TRUNC( "Date" )`) and then to get the last value per group you can take the maximum:

```
SELECT name, MAX( "Date" )
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY name, TRUNC( "Date" )
```

> my date do not have times in it.

Yes, they do. SQL Developer is just not showing it.

Either, change the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter - as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6838744/1509264).

Or [alter the oracle session parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43571398/1509264).

Or format the output as a string:

```
SELECT name,
       TO_CHAR( MAX( "Date" ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS last_date
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY name, TRUNC( "Date" )
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT name, MAX(TO_DATE("Date", 'DD-MM-YYYY')) last_date
FROM 
(
    SELECT 1 AS id, 'a' AS name, '01-Feb-2017' AS "Date" 
        FROM dual UNION
    SELECT 2, 'a', '01-Feb-2017'
        FROM dual UNION
    SELECT 3, 'a', '01-Feb-2017'
        FROM dual UNION
    SELECT 4, 'b', '02-Feb-2017'
        FROM dual union
    SELECT 5, 'b', '02-Feb-2017'
        FROM dual UNION
    SELECT 6, 'c', '04-Feb-2017'
        FROM dual UNION
    SELECT 7, 'c', '04-Feb-2017'
        FROM dual
) mytable
GROUP BY name
```

Output:

```
    NAME    LAST_DATE
1   a   01.02.2017 00:00:00
2   c   04.02.2017 00:00:00
3   b   02.02.2017 00:00:00
```

Explanation :

You group your result by name, you want the last date, thus max(date). But you have a string as date. So first, you convert it into a datetime.

If you want a different output could you provide it to us ... cause it's unclear at the moment.

Comment: From the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm#SQLRF00620): `CONVERT` converts a character string from one character set to another. This does not appear to be an Oracle answer. You probably mean to use the `TRUNC` function.

Comment: my bad. in the first post edit, the tag was sql-server or at least It thought it was

Comment: The [sql] tag means the SQL language and is not a short hand for MS SQL Server (although some posters do use it as such).