# how to change the date to time in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle

I have to put in `STIMING` a time when I insert I use `TO_DATE` function but it give me date not time and it should be time.

This is the table and the code that i use

SQL> select * from shift;

```
       SNO SNAME                STIMING
---------- -------------------- ---------
    121323 morning              01-APR-17
    112232 evening              01-APR-17
    665342 afternoon            01-APR-17

SQL> update shift
2  set  STIMING= ('07:00:00 HH,MI,SS') 
3  where SNO=121323;
set  STIMING= ('07:00:00 HH,MI,SS')             
 *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

Comment: Add to question table description, so that people can answer you.

Comment: You must provide a DATE component for the `DATE` [data type](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT413). Select an arbitrary date, eg 2000-01-01, and store all values as time on 2000-01-01, eg `TO_DATE('2000-01-01 07:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to put in `STIMING` a time

Oracle does not have a `TIME` datatype. The `DATE` data type is always stored internally as [7-bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264) and is always composed of year (2-bytes) and month, day, hours, minutes and seconds (1-byte each).

You **cannot** not have a year, month or day component of a `DATE`.

If you want a time on its own then you will have to store it as a different data type or store the year/month/day and ignore that component.

When you are `SELECT`ing the `STIMING` column it is not showing the time component. You can change this by changing the default date format which is set in the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter.

You can review this parameter using:

```
SELECT VALUE FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

You can set this value within your current session using:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

*(Note: this does not change the value for any other users.)*

When you insert the date you can use:

```
INSERT INTO shift ( SNO, SNAME, STIMING)
VALUES ( 121323, 'morning', TO_DATE( '01-APR-2017 07:00' DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI' ) )
```

Or, an ANSI `TIMESTAMP` literal (which will be implicitly cast to the `DATE` format of the column):

```
INSERT INTO shift ( SNO, SNAME, STIMING)
VALUES ( 121323, 'morning', TIMESTAMP '2017-04-01 07:00:00' )
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to avoid updates, change your insert part from `to_date` with no formatting param to `to_date( colname, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')`