# Unable to convert date and varchar to date in Oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g, varchar

I have following query:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(date || ' ' || time, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM table;
```

`date` is `DATE`

`time` is `VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)`

After executing query I get `27-OCT-16` without time instead of `27-OCT-16 14:26:09`.

Is there any solution?

Comment: and what is the value of `time` ?

Comment: time is `14:26:09`

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the issue is but I would try the following: `SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(date, 'DD-MON-YY') || ' ' || time, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM table;`

Comment: Another possibility is that Oracle is returning the date & time correctly but formatting it for output without the time part. That is, your query is working as is (but dependent on the NLS settings), but not displaying a time even though it is returned.

Comment: Are you sure that the DATE value does not contain time component already?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes. `date` is `27-OCT-16` and `time` is `14:26:09`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[TL;DR]** Your date has a time component but you are relying on implicit string conversions and the default format model (probably `DD-MON-YY`) does not display the time component.

---

Your query:

```
SELECT TO_DATE( date || ' ' || time, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS' )
FROM   table;
```

The `DATE` does not have a format; it is stored internally as [7-bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264) and it is the the client program which you are using to access the database which will apply its own formatting to the date (which you can usually set via the preferences in that program).

For SQL/Plus and SQL developer, this is usually the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter. Which you can find the format of using the query:

```
SELECT VALUE FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'
```

Trying to concatenate a `DATE` with a string will implicitly convert the date to a string and the query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(
         TO_CHAR(
           date,
           ( SELECT VALUE FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' )
         )
         || time,
         'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'
       )
FROM   table
```

And then the second implicit conversion to something the client program can display will make your query the equivalent of:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE(
           TO_CHAR(
             date,
             (SELECT VALUE FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
           )
           || time,
           'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'
         ),
         (SELECT VALUE FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
       )
FROM   table
```

I would guess that your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `DD-MON-YY` (or `DD-MON-YYYY`) - otherwise the initial conversion would fail and this has no time component so the UI's conversion from a date back to a string also does not include a time component.

If you want the `DATE` with a specific format then just use `TO_CHAR` to show it.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE(
           TO_CHAR( date, 'DD-MON-YYYY' ) || ' ' || time,
           'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
         ),
         'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
       )
FROM   table;
```

Or you could [alter the session variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43571398/1509264) (but this is likely to break your initial implicit string conversion) so, don't do that, just change all your implicit string conversions to explicit ones and specify the format model you are using.