# Count the inserted rows per day per type

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to create a query which will show the amount of query's inserted each day sorted by a type. This sounds pretty vague so I will demonstrate it below:

```
+----+------+----------+
| id | type | inserted |
+----+------+----------+
|  1 | a    | 1/2/2017 |
|  2 | a    | 1/2/2017 |
|  3 | a    | 2/2/2017 |
|  4 | b    | 1/2/2017 |
|  5 | b    | 1/2/2017 |
|  6 | b    | 2/2/2017 |
|  7 | b    | 3/2/2017 |
|  8 | b    | 3/2/2017 |
+----+------+----------+
```

The result needs to be:

```
+------+----------+--------+
| type |   date   | amount |
+------+----------+--------+
| a    | 1/2/2017 |      2 |
| a    | 2/2/2017 |      1 |
| b    | 1/2/2017 |      2 |
| b    | 2/2/2017 |      1 |
| b    | 3/2/2017 |      2 |
+------+----------+--------+
```

I already tried some queries with GROUP BY and DISTINCT but I can't figure out how to get no duplicates.

I already tried:
`SELECT date, type, count(*) FROM table GROUP BY date, type` but that gives me duplicate date/type combinations. This is what it returns:

[image: duplicates]

Comment: Can you show what have you tried ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using group by on multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421388/using-group-by-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: I tried `SELECT date, type, count(*) FROM table GROUP BY date, type` but it has duplicate date/type combination.

Comment: With the data you've posted, I don't see any duplicates when running your query.

Comment: The data I posted is an example becuase the table I am working with is quite big and is in a foreign language. The problem might be related to that then.

Comment: I edited the post to show what my results are.

Comment: The dates have a time component you are not seeing - change the SQL developer preferences as [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6838744/1509264). Use `TRUNC()` to truncate all the time components to midnight when you are grouping.

Comment: @MT0 Thanks! Could you post this as answer so I can accept it? It worked btw.

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen I [posted it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42253810/1509264) 2 hours ago shortly after you posted the question.

Comment: Ah allright. Could you edit the post with the explanation so it will be more clear to other people aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by `type` and by day (i.e. `TRUNC( inserted )`):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( id, type, inserted ) AS
  SELECT 1, 'a', TO_DATE( '2017-02-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'a', TO_DATE( '2017-02-01 01:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'a', TO_DATE( '2017-02-02 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'b', TO_DATE( '2017-02-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'b', TO_DATE( '2017-02-01 01:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'b', TO_DATE( '2017-02-02 01:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 'b', TO_DATE( '2017-02-03 02:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 'b', TO_DATE( '2017-02-03 03:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT type,
       TRUNC( inserted ) AS "date",
       COUNT(1) AS amount
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY type,
      TRUNC( inserted );
```

**Output**:

```
TYPE date                AMOUNT
---- ------------------- ------
a    2017-02-01 00:00:00      2
a    2017-02-02 00:00:00      1
b    2017-02-01 00:00:00      2
b    2017-02-02 00:00:00      1
b    2017-02-03 00:00:00      2
```

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen Did you run it as typed? It works for me on Oracle 11gR2.

Comment: `Selected incosistend with group by`

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen Your dates have a time component that SQL developer is not showing you. You need to use `TRUNC( inserted )` in both the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Is that works for you?

```
select type, inserted,  count(inserted)
  from tmp_table 
  group by type, inserted
```

Comment: SQL Developer doesn't recognize the `[]` tags.

Comment: The square brackets are not valid oracle syntax.

Comment: No it gives me duplicates.