# What is Oracle Date Format and How to set that?

Tags: oracle

In MySQL :

```
CREATE TABLE t_users (username VARCHAR(30), password VARCHAR(30), date_added(DATE))
```

As I know for default format date in MySQL is like this : 2013-06-24

That worked.

Now I create table in ORACLE :

```
CREATE TABLE T_USERS (USERNAME VARCHAR(30), PASSWORD VARCHAR(30), DATE_ADDED(DATE))
```

My question is :
1. What is default date format in oracle ?
2. Can I use format like MySQL date format like this : 2013-06-24 ?

Please, need your advice.
Thank you

Comment: The short answer would be: try it and see, but this question may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837974/oracles-default-date-format-is-yyyy-mm-dd-oh-dear-god-why . (It's also the first result I get when I google "default oracle date format".)

Comment: Do you mean to ask if you can use the ISO-8601 date format? if so, then yes, you do it like this `date '2013-06-24'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After connecting to oracle you can alter your session:

```
SQL> SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;

SYSDATE
---------
24-JUN-13

SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;

SYSDATE
----------
2013-06-24
```

You have to run it after new connection is established.

In order to display it in different way in Oracle SQL Developer:

Tools -> Preferences -> Database -> NLS -> Date Format

Comment: Hi, I have tried but it's not change the date format. Am I wrong with something ?

Comment: Can you use function? is it okay to use TO_DATE('2013-06-24', 'YYYY-MM-DD') or DATE'2013-06-24'?