# What is the format, for inserting DATE values in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

In Oracle SQL, I read that the default date format is `'YYYY-MON-DD'`

But however, when I run this query:

```
  SELECT TO_CHAR
    (SYSDATE) "NOW"
    FROM DUAL;
```

It returns  :

> `23-APR-15`

I was expecting something like '2015-APR-23' though..

Why is that? thanks

See this question- [Oracle's default date format is YYYY-MM-DD, WHY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837974/oracles-default-date-format-is-yyyy-mm-dd-why)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default date format is whatever is specified by your session's `nls_date_format`.  You should never, ever write code that relies on the session's `nls_date_format` however, since that depends on things like the user's preference, their country and region, etc.  You should be using explicit conversions and/or date literals (date 'yyyy-mm-dd') in your code rather than relying on implicit conversion.  If you care about the format of the string that is returned, you'd need to provide an explicit format mask in your `to_char` call.

It appears that your session's `nls_date_format` is `DD-MON-RR` which is a common default for an English language install.  Someone else's default may be `YYYY-MON-DD`.  Someone else may have yet another default.