# How to remove "00:00:00.0" from "2012-03-04 00:00:00.0" in java?

Tags: java, oracle, date, format

I hava java program , the program get table 'Employees' from oracle Database 11G

the problem is ,

java program get the Hire_Date Column in this format “YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00.0”

I want get the date in this format “YYYY-MM-DD"

How can I solve This Problem ?

the photo will explian the problem

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip3RR.png

Comment: Could you provide some code that you use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469507/how-can-i-change-the-date-format-in-java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837974/oracles-default-date-format-is-yyyy-mm-dd-why use this to solve your problem

Comment: Use a DateFormat of some kind

Comment: What's the datatype of your `HIRE_DATE` column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this as part of your select statement:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY') HIRE_DATE_TRUNC FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

Use of `to_char` to format dates is [described here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm).  Alternatively, you could use a `SimpleDateFormat` to do the same thing in Java after the data has been extracted:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");

Date d = new Date();
String formatted = sdf.format(d);
System.out.println(formatted);
```