# How do you determine the format for crystal date parameters?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

So I'm using a windows script to use [Visual Cut](http://www.milletsoftware.com/Download/Visual_CUT_User_Manual.pdf) to run a report.  That report takes in two date parameters (along with additional params).  The script was working when I first tested it, but when I went to demonstrate it to a co-worker it stopped.  It turns out that Crystal/Visual Cut needed the date parameter in a different format (initially dd/mm/yyyy worked, but now it requires yyyy/mm/dd). How does Crystal decide what format it needs, and how can I make sure my input adapts to that format?

EDIT: Current workaround is to require 'yyyy/mm/dd' format, and I changed the type on the parameters in the report from dates to strings, and then I explicitly call `cdate` on the values.  I just want to know

**a)** Where the datemask used for date parameters comes from and

**b)** If passing 'yyyy/mm/dd' to `cdate` will ever fail (assuming a valid date).

Comment: What is your database date format?

Comment: @Siva DB doesn't have a date format, it's up to the client http://stackoverflow.com/a/1838369/4966481

Answer (score 0):

Passing string values and converting them to date, time , number etc might be a problem because you have no control over the user settings. Check what is the difference between the default date format on both computers.

Comment: Tests were run on the same computer, but at different dates.

Comment: Any chance that the dates were with replaceable month and day numbers . For example if the date is 12/05/2015 the system can read as December 5th or May 12th. However , if you try  12/14/2015 there is just one option to get date from this string.

Comment: I saw your "EDIT". Do you need to use VisualCut or you are just testing it ? Seems like you are trying to adjust your environment to the product instead of the product to work in your environment.

Comment: No I tested that specifically (also note that mm/dd/yyyy still doesn't work).  And yeah, we already have the product deployed for a ton of reports, trying to use it in a way it wasn't quite designed for to improve a workflow issue.  Seems to be working okay now, just worried about why the date format seemed to change on me.