# How to change Oracle Insert Query Date Format to to_date in sqlc

Tags: oracle, sql-insert, dateformatter, sqlcl

Good day,

within sqlcl I will like to run a query that build a insert statement. Such as:

```
SELECT /*insert*/* FROM TABLE;
```

but each date value is returned as `to_timestamp('date', 'format')` and I want to get `to_date('date', 'format')` instead.

What do I need to set to make this thing happen?

Thanks!!

### Editted:

For Example... I have the table datesaving with two columns id, and date. 
If I run this query

`SELECT /*insert*/ id,date FROM datesaving ;`

I get

`Insert into DATASAVING (ID, DATE) values (1,to_timestamp('2016-02-15 11:05:07','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));`

and I want to get this instead

`Insert into DATASAVING (ID, DATE) values (1,to_date('2016-02-15 11:05:07','RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));`

I know i can change de nls_format, but I dont know hot to change this.

Comment: Sorry this is not clear. Please explain what commands you are running and post what output you get (the whole thing or at least enough to provide proper context).

Comment: I edited my question, hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the metadata we in sqlcl are getting back tells us a DATE column is a timestamp so the code treats it as such. However, it will work just fine.

```
SQL> create table test_insert(id number,dt date,ts timestamp);

Table TEST_INSERT created.

SQL> insert into test_insert values(1,sysdate,systimestamp);

1 row inserted.

SQL> set sqlformat insert
SQL> select * from test_insert;
REM INSERTING into TEST_INSERT
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into TEST_INSERT (ID,DT,TS) values (1,to_timestamp('02-FEB-18','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),to_timestamp('02-FEB-18 01.47.57.017643000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'));

<<<copy pasted to run the output >>>

SQL> insert into TEST_INSERT (ID,DT,TS) values (1,to_timestamp('02-FEB-18','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),to_timestamp('02-FEB-18 01.47.57.017643000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'));

1 row inserted.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the trick to get the missing time part of the DATE type in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837974/oracles-default-date-format-is-yyyy-mm-dd-why).

Just type the following command BEFORE typing your SELECT statements:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS AM';
```

The INSERT statements will take this format into account:

```
SQL> insert into TEST_INSERT (ID,DT,TS) values (1,to_timestamp('02-02-18 01.47.57','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'),to_timestamp('02-FEB-18 01.47.57.017643000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'));
```

### Note 1

I took the `DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM` format as it was the generated one of your example (without `XFF`, see below).

In my case, I have been given the `DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SS` format. This shows the generated format for INSERT statements depends on NLS (National Language Support, i.e. locale) parameters (like `NLS_TERRITORY`) that should be set first  to guaranty the portability of your code.

Use `SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS;` to get the content of your parameters and set them at the beginning of your script.

### Note 2

According to the given format, you must remove the `XFF` part at the end which does not make sense with a DATE format because the one doesn't include fractional seconds.
So `DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM` becomes `DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS AM`.