# Why is DATE data type treated like TIMESTAMP(0) data type in Oracle mode in H2?

Tags: oracle, date, timestamp, h2

According to the [H2 documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility), in the `Oracle` compatibility mode:

> DATE data type is treated like TIMESTAMP(0) data type.

Meantime, `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP(0)` datatypes are not the same in Oracle. Compare:

`SELECT CAST(SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP(0)), CAST(SYSDATE AS DATE) from dual`

gives

`25-MAR-22 13.07.42.000000000   25-MAR-22`

respectively.

In particular, this weird treating of `DATE` as `TIMESTAMP(0)` influences on how H2 calculates the difference between two dates.
Again, in Oracle:

`SELECT CAST(TO_DATE('2022-01-05',  'YYYY-MM-DD') AS TIMESTAMP(0)) - CAST(TO_DATE('2022-01-01',  'YYYY-MM-DD') AS TIMESTAMP(0)) from dual`

gives

`+04 00:00:00.000000`

and

`SELECT CAST(TO_DATE('2022-01-05',  'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DATE) - CAST(TO_DATE('2022-01-01',  'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DATE) from dual`

produces just:

`4`

Apparently, for H2 both above queries produce the result in nanoseconds and not days as expected.

So, it is an H2 bug or I am missing something?

Comment: The `DATE` data type in Oracle represents a timestamp (includes date and time info). Oracle is an old database and back in the 70s they were just trying to survive without paying too much attention to naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

> Meantime, `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP(0)` datatypes are not the same in Oracle

Oracle differs from many other RDBMS in that its `DATE` data type **ALWAYS** contains both a date and a time component. Its implementation [predates the ANSI standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70695263/1509264).

In Oracle, if you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ts TIMESTAMP(0), dt DATE);
```

and insert the data:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (ts, dt) VALUES (SYSDATE, SYSDATE);
```

Then you can look at the binary data being stored using the `DUMP` function:

```sql
SELECT DUMP(ts) AS dump_ts,
       DUMP(dt) AS dump_dt
FROM   table_name;
```

Which outputs:

> | DUMP_TS | DUMP_DT |
> | --- | --- |
> | Typ=180 Len=7: 120,122,3,25,15,13,37 | Typ=12 Len=7: 120,122,3,25,15,13,37 |

Then you can see that they are both stored as 7-byte binary values:

- `120` = Century + 100
- `122` = Year-of-century + 100
- `3` = Month
- `25` = Day
- `15` = Hour + 1
- `13` = Minutes + 1
- `37` = Seconds + 1

And the binary values are identical (the only difference is in the meta-data `Typ` where 180 = `TIMESTAMP` and 12 = `DATE`).

Effectively, they are stored identically.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ca5578c71b46a6b3ea2338f67800f989)*

---

#### However

The side-effects of a `TIMESTAMP` vs. a `DATE` data type in Oracle may lead to different effects.

- When you subtract a `TIMESTAMP` and either a `TIMESTAMP` or a `DATE` then the return value is an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type.

  When you subtract a `DATE` and a `DATE` then the default return value is a `NUMBER` representing the number of days difference.
- When you display a `TIMESTAMP` then the client application you are using may default to using the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` session parameter to format the timestamp as a string and the default for this parameter will typically show date, time and fractional seconds.

  When you display a `DATE` then the client application you are using may default to using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter to format the date as a string and the default for this parameter will show date but not time (and there will never be any fractional seconds to show). Just because the client application may chose not to show the time component does not mean that the time component does not exist.

  If you set the session parameters using:

  ```sql
  ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
  ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
  ```

  Then, provided your client application is using those parameters to format them, they will display identically.

The problem you are seeing with the difference in Oracle is due to these side effects.

Comment: Still. How does it answer my question?  Perhaps H2 is doing oversimplification by treating DATE as TIMESTAMP(0) here?

Comment: Also,
> if you set the session parameters using: (...)
but this is not a default behavior. And I doubt if the result of subtraction between TIMESTMAP(0) and DATE will be the same.

Comment: @Andremoniy Setting the session parameters makes zero difference to the result of any subtraction. The session parameters are Oracle's internal default format model for implicit casts from strings-to-dates and vice versa but subtraction does not use them at all. Some client applications also use the session parameters as default when formatting output but that is a feature of the client application and not the database.

Comment: @Andremoniy H2 works for multiple RDBMS and its assumption will be that a `DATE` data type matches the ISO/ANSI standard. That is true for many RDBMS but it is not true for Oracle as Oracle's date date type was defined 7 years before the ISO/ANSI standards existed and has both a date and time component. To maintain consistency, the closest ISO/ANSI standard data type that an Oracle date can be mapped to would be a `TIMESTAMP(0)` data type.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is

> So, it is an H2 bug or I am missing something?

than the the answer would be:
No, it is not a bug, and what you've missed is the fact, that compatibility modes in H2 are just that - attempt to reach with minimal efforts maximum compatibility with different databases.
H2 is not an emulator for any non-standard features (quirks) of those databases.
It that particular case, to achieve identical behaviour would require to introduce new non-standard data type, which goes beyond "minimal effort" level.

Answer (score -1):

The different in the output of the values in the first query is down to the session's NLS settings. These control the display format for dates and timestamps:

```
sho parameter nls_date_format

NAME            TYPE   VALUE       
--------------- ------ ----------- 
nls_date_format string DD-MON-YYYY 

sho parameter nls_timestamp_format

NAME                 TYPE   VALUE                     
-------------------- ------ ------------------------- 
nls_timestamp_format string DD-MON-YYYY HH24.MI.SSXFF 

SELECT CAST(SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP(0)), CAST(SYSDATE AS DATE) from dual;

CAST(SYSDATEASTIMESTAMP(0))    CAST(SYSDAT
------------------------------ -----------
25-MAR-2022 12.18.24.000000000 25-MAR-2022
```

If you change these to be the same format, both expressions return the same result:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

SELECT CAST(SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP(0)), CAST(SYSDATE AS DATE) from dual;

CAST(SYSDATEASTIMEST CAST(SYSDATEASDATE) 
-------------------- --------------------
25-MAR-2022 12:17:43 25-MAR-2022 12:17:43
```

So they both contain the full date + time with no fractional seconds.

Note that while `date` and `timestamp(0)` have the same precision, as your further examples show they work differently:

- Subtracting one `date` from another returns the number of days between the values as a `number`
- Subtracting a `timestamp` from a `date` or `timestamp` returns an `interval`

So the result of:

```
SELECT CAST(TO_DATE('2022-01-05',  'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DATE) - CAST(TO_DATE('2022-01-01',  'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DATE) from dual
```

Is 4 *days*.

Comment: Sorry, but how does it answer my question? The fact is that the subtraction result differs between TIMESTAMP(0) and DATE types

Comment: @Andremoniy What exactly is your question? I can't comment on how H2 works, but with the Oracle expressions both return 4 days, just in different data types. When working with timestamps the result is an `interval`, when both are dates the value is a number.

Comment: >  but with the Oracle expressions both return 4 days, just in different data types

Comment: That is exactly the problem. In H2 both types DATE and TIMESTAMP(0) lead to the same INTERVAL in nanos, instead of DAYS.

Comment: My question was not about Oracle, but about H2. There is a discrepancy between the expected behavior and actual one. That's why you answer does not answer my inquiry

Comment: Also, the result of DATE subtraction in Oracle is a number; while for TIMESTAMP(0) it is an interval. Two completely different data types. For H2 it is always an INTERVAL, so there is no way to get the number. Do you see the difference? And I am talking about the specific Oracle comparability mode. So, yes, it is a question for more H2 experts rather than Oracle ones.

Comment: OK, so maybe use H2 examples in the question as well/instead of Oracle

Comment: Okay that makes sense: I will add H2 examples as well, thanks